# Deeplearning4j Invoice extraction

Tags: machine-learning, invoice, deeplearning4j

Does anyone try to use Deeplearning4j to extract data from invoice?
The idea is to train model, then send extracted text of incvoice as an input and receive predicted fields like invoice number, invoice date, customer name, etc.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is not a programming question, you should ask on another forum. Quora or Data Science SE maybe.